# How to get the action name in freemarker in Struts2?

Tags: java, struts2, freemarker

e.g http://localhost/market/pcsuite/edit.action

Can I get the action name "edit" in the freemarker file edit.flt?

Comment: Any reason to use `FreeMarker`?

Comment: All the pages here are writen in FreeMarker. Is it bad to use Freemarker? @lschin

Comment: Not... bad, but not preferred by most. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/freemarker?sort=votes&pagesize=50

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<@s.property value="com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext.name" />
```

**Or**

```
<@s.set var="actionName" value="com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext.name" />

<#-- Use as -->

<@s.property value="actionName" />

<#-- Or other FreeMarker Tags -->
```

**Or**

Create a getter in `action class`, e.g.

```
public String getActionName() {
    return ActionContext.getContext().getName();
}
```

```
<@s.property value="actionName" />
```